# How can I take a .avi file from a webcam and transform it into a .mat file for use in matlab?

Tags: matlab, webcam, avi

I am using a commercial webcam (GearHead) which records .avi video files.  I want to analyze the individual frames of the .avi file  matlab code, but the series of frames first need to be in .mat format. I don't need/want audio. How can I convert the .avi file to a .mat file?

thank you.

Comment: Maybe useful to have a look: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/81210#answer_90938

Comment: Have you tried [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/import_export/read-video-files.html)?

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of MATLAB you can use the command `aviread` to read an .avi file into MATLAB. In newer versions the preferred method is to use `VideoReader`. Once you've read it in, you can save the data to a .mat file.

Comment: Code:  
A = aviread('firstAttempt_1395344631.avi');  

Response:  
Error using VideoReader/init (line 447)  
Failed to initialize internal resources.  

Error in VideoReader (line 132)  
obj.init(fileName);  

Error in untitled (line 1)  
A = VideoReader('firstAttempt_1395344631.avi');  

Any suggestions? I can't use aviread, as I get the response:  

Error using aviread (line 148)  
Only uncompressed AVI movies can be read on UNIX.  

Error in untitled (line 1)  
A = aviread('firstAttempt_1395344631.avi');